# How to intensify the 3d aspect of a curve plot with Maple?

Tags: curve, maple, plot3d

I was trying to built a 3d plot to represent a parametrized curve in space using Maple, something like (x(t), y(t), t). I could! But the thing is that I need it as an image, so the reader will not be able to rotate this result as I am now, so I need to choice a favorable angle, and I just can't. I was wondering if it's possible to insert any type of a background like this one we usually make it appear when using Python:

[Grid on planes as a background, I think it might help in this sense of representation of a curve in space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F08N3.png)

or maybe a color varying over the curve as t changes.

Here's what I tried:

```
with(DEtools):
DEplot3d({diff(x(t),t) = y(t),diff(y(t),t) = (1 - x(t)^2)*y(t) - x(t)},[x(t),y(t)],t=0..15,[[x(0)=0,y(0)=0.1]],stepsize=.1,x=-2.5..2.5,linecolor=black,axes=framed,thickness=1,obsrange=FALSE);
```

And this is the best manner I could adjust it:

[I know it's not that bad at all, but I really think it could get better with something else that emphasizes that sense of a 3d object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEuSo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could construct such a mesh of gray lines.

You could also add some perspective to the 3D plot, to give a sense of depth.

You could also color the curve is some way that conveyed distance or depth. (Below, I color it with a gradient in the first axis's dimension.)

[image]

```
with(plots): with(plottools):
P := DEtools[DEplot3d]({diff(x(t),t) = y(t),
                    diff(y(t),t) = (1 - x(t)^2)*y(t) - x(t)},
                   [x(t),y(t)],t=0..15,[[x(0)=0,y(0)=0.1]],
                   stepsize=.05,x=-2.5..2.5,
                   linecolor=black,axes=framed,thickness=2,
                   obsrange=false):

rngs := [op(indets(P,specfunc(VIEW))[1])]:

meshlines:=display(
           seq(line([x,op([2,1],rngs),op([3,1],rngs)],
                    [x,op([2,2],rngs),op([3,1],rngs)],
                    color=gray,thickness=0),
               x=[seq(rngs[1], numelems=7)]),
           seq(line([op([1,1],rngs),y,op([3,1],rngs)],
                    [op([1,2],rngs),y,op([3,1],rngs)],
                    color=gray,thickness=0),
               y=[seq(rngs[2], numelems=7)]),
           seq(line([op([1,1],rngs),op([2,1],rngs),z],
                    [op([1,1],rngs),op([2,2],rngs),z],
                    color=gray,thickness=0),
               z=[seq(rngs[3], numelems=7)]),
           seq(line([op([1,1],rngs),y,op([3,1],rngs)],
                    [op([1,1],rngs),y,op([3,2],rngs)],
                    color=gray,thickness=0),
               y=[seq(rngs[2], numelems=7)]),
           seq(line([x,op([2,1],rngs),op([3,1],rngs)],
                    [x,op([2,1],rngs),op([3,2],rngs)],
                    color=gray,thickness=0),
               x=[seq(rngs[1], numelems=7)]),
           seq(line([op([1,1],rngs),op([2,1],rngs),z],
                    [op([1,2],rngs),op([2,1],rngs),z],
                    color=gray,thickness=0),
               z=[seq(rngs[3], numelems=7)])):

newP := spacecurve(op(1,indets(P,specfunc(CURVES))[1]),
               thickness=3,
               colorscheme=["xgradient",["#C0FFFF",black]]):

display(meshlines, newP, axes=framed,
        labels=[t,x(t),y(t)],
        projection=0.76);
```

Comment: Wow!! That's exactly what I was expecting as a result! You made it perfectly! Thank you! I naively thought that this meshgrid could be done with just one simple command.